# Hyperledger Fabric unable to create a channel with only one organization

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

i have this `configtx.yaml` configuration after creating orderer genesis block, channel and anchor peer  configuration i entered the on a peer cli end try to create a channel i get error saying

```
2020-01-04 06:02:06.398 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 04b pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0005336f0, CONNECTING
2020-01-04 06:02:06.399 UTC [grpc] HandleSubConnStateChange -> DEBU 04c pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0005336f0, READY
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- Attempted to include a member which is not in the consortium
```

can some see what i have missed?

```
Organizations:

    - &OrdererOrg
        Name: OrdererOrg
        ID: OrdererMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/bionic.com/msp
    - &Org1
        Name: Org1

        ID: Org1MSP

        MSPDir: ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.bionic.com/msp

        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1.peer', 'Org1.admin', 'Org1.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1.peer', 'Org1.admin', 'Org1.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1.peer', 'Org1.admin', 'Org1.client')"


        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.org1.bionic.com
              Port: 7051

Capabilities:
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
...
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
...
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
...

Application: &ApplicationDefaults

    Organizations:

    Policies:
...
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

    OrdererType: solo

    Addresses:
        - orderer.bionic.com:7050
...
    Organizations:

    Policies:
...
Profiles:

    OneOrgOrdererGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
    OneOrgChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

this is the code i have executed inside a peer cli

```
peer channel create -o orderer.bionic.com:7050 -c bionicchannel -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls 
--cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/bionic.com/orderers/orderer.bionic.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.bionic.com-cert.pem
```

i have tried removing the consortium section completly and generated new configtx.yaml file but then i get the error saying i can not create an orderer genesis block without a consortium definition.

Comment: Why do you have Organizations and Capabilities twice under 'Profiles.OneOrgChannel.Application'?

Comment: that was by mistake. do you see other problem

Answer (score 1):

You have to update the `OneOrgOrdererGenesis` Profile.

In the orderer section you are making `*Org1` as the orderer. Change it to `*OrdererOrg`.

```
Profiles:

    OneOrgOrdererGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
```

Create genesis block again and start a new network.